# Auto refresh of page not working when getting all images from a folder

Tags: javascript, php

I am capturing a few streams and converting each stream into a thumbnail. Each thumbnail stream is stored in its own image name. Meaning there is 1 image file for each stream and just getting over written every 5 seconds. I have a page that displays these thumbnails and auto refreshes without blinking. The following code works great for just 1 stream but once other streams start to get into the folder, the page no longer refreshes

```
    <script>
    function updateImage() {
    obj = document.imagename;
    obj.src = obj.src + "?" + Math.random();
    setTimeout("updateImage()",2000);
    }
    </script>

    <body onload="updateImage();">
    <?php  
    $dirname = "thumbnails/";
    $images = glob($dirname."/*.png");

    foreach($images as $thumbs) {
    echo "<img name=imagename src=".$thumbs."?t=".time().">";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: Where are you refreshing the page?

Comment: The code that I posted is all I have on the thumbnail page. With just 1 image in the folder, the page updates the image great. As soon as the folder gets the 2nd image, the 2 images stop updating.

Comment: You are not refreshing the page, you are just resetting the source of the image you already have in the page every 2 seconds so since you change the image (it must have the same name to work, right?) it loads the new 1

Comment: Yes, the name of the image never changes. I am appending the time at the end of the image file name so that the page shows the new image.  My problem is that once there is a 2nd image file in the folder, nothing works.  So image1.png keeps getting updated and the page displays the update every 2 seconds. I then add image2.png and both images do not update.

Comment: The reason image 1 breaks when adding image 2 is because `document.imagename` is an array when having more then 1 image and you are treating it like an object

Comment: So would it be best if I just put the image names inside a div and have the div refreshed every 2 seconds?

Comment: Do you always expect the same amount of images and will they always have the same names when updating?

Comment: There will be about 30 images in that folder and all these images will be updated under their same name.

Comment: So you can hard code the images on the page and then do a `foreach` in the JS to loop thru `document.imagename`

Comment: Thanks. That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are refreshing the page, the reason it works with 1 image (when you have an image in the folder and you load your page and then you put in another image with the same name) is because as you are changing the `src` of the image every 2 seconds it loads the new one. When you do it with 2 images its not working as `document.imagename` is an array when having more then 1 image and you are treating it like an object.

The solution would be to either reload the PHP with ajax or if you dont mind the blink use this: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" >` Or if you know how many images will be there and their names you can hard code the images and do the loop in your JS not in your PHP

Comment: With 30 thumbnails going on, that flash is annoying. Your suggestion with foreach worked but I will also try to load the php page with ajax and see how that goes in case there will be a case where I don;t know how many different thumbnails will be generated